# Weird behaviour when taking input from the terminal using $ScriptCommandLine

Tags: scripting

I am trying to create a .wl file that can be run from the terminal using wolframscript. The script looks something like

```
input = $ScriptCommandLine[[2;;Length[$ScriptCommandLine]]]
pwd = DirectoryName[$InputFileName]

Get["/Users/xcodeking/foo.m"];

data = {deltaExt \[Rule] input[[1]], cc \[Rule] input[[2]], deltaMin \[Rule] input[[3]], hMin \[Rule] input[[4]] };
(* data = {deltaExt -> 2, cc -> 2, deltaMin -> 7/8, hMin -> 2 }; *)

file = pwd <> "trial_run.xml"

WriteSDP[data, file, {4, 4, 4}, 10, 0, 1/8, 100]
```

Here the function WriteSDP is inside the file `foo.m` and does a bunch of computations and saves the output in `file`. The script is called from the terminal as

```
wolframscript -script foobar.wl 2 2 7/8 2
```

where `foobar.wl` is the file where the above script is stored. If I uncomment the second `data` and comment the first one out, the script works perfectly. However, if I don't do that and run the script with the input as mentioned, I get a bunch of errors (the precise error is that of encountering a bunch of 1/0).

Is there some kind of issue with how the input is being handled? Is there a string vs float problem? I am completely clueless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the problem was with it being passed as a string vs a number. Changing the first line to

```
input = Read[StringToStream[#], Number] &/@ $ScriptCommandLine[[2;;Length[$ScriptCommandLine]]]
```

solved the problem

Comment: Probably interesting to know: there is also ``Internal`StringToMInteger`` if you are looking for a simple and fast way to convert strings to integers...